# Poisson Counting Process over Variable Threshold

Tags: gamma-distribution, poisson-process, threshold

Let's consider a Poisson Counting Process $N(t)$ with generation rate $\lambda$ and a piece-wise constant threshold $M(t)$ that changes with time.
$$ M(t)=m_i \ \  for \ \  t\in(t_{i-1},t_{i}],\ i\in \mathbb{N},\  t\geq 0 $$
Is there a way to write $P[N(t)>M(t)]$?

I've been thinking of looking for an iterative solution using Bayes Theorem.
For example, if $m_1=m_2=m$ then we can define $p_1=P[N(t_1)>m]$ and $$p_2=P[N(t_2)>m|N(t_1)\leq m]=\frac{P[N(t_1)>m]-P[N(t_2)>m]}{(1-p_1)}$$

However, how can I treat the case where the threshold changes with time (piecewise constant)?

I have been thinking of writing the Poisson Process in terms of a Gamma distribution (Erlang). At every interval one would have a different Gamma based on the new threshold and the cumulative probability that the process had already crossed the threshold in the previous steps.

EDIT: Here I'm trying to simplify the problem to understand the core of it and find a solution.

[image: Poisson counting process over variable threhsold]

In the image above I'm depicting the core of the problem I'm trying to solve. I want to find:

$$ P[T<t_2 | T>t_1] $$

The population of experiments that end up crossing the threshold before t2 is being thinned out by the fact that the threshold was lower before t1. Here is an example simulation (don't mind the vertical lines) of the crossing times (in orange) and the gamma distributions for the two thresholds.

[image: Simulation example]

I'm looking for a mathematical way to express the probability above and, if possible, to determine the distribution of time crossings between t1 and t2. Any insight or tip that would point me in the right direction would be great too.